Using a breakpoint in a multi-threaded C# application
When you hit a breakpoint in a multi-threaded C# application, I thought that all threads were stopped.
So, I expected, when hitting a breakpoint, that I would be able to thaw other threads, but instead of that, I got the possibility to freeze other threads, as you can see in the following screenshot:

This caused some confusion at first.
Now I believe the situation is as follows:

Hitting a breakpoint pauses all threads.
The feature "Freeze" means that, even after continuing after the breakpoint, I have the possibility to pause other threads.
In case I want to "thaw" those threads, I can pause my application (which also means "pausing all threads"), and thaw those threads.

Can anybody confirm my thought or correct it? (I'd like to stress that I'm working with C# (.Net), where multi-threading might be handled differently than in native languages.)
Is there any documentation, which confirms this?

I thought that all threads were stopped - they are. They all run again briefly if you hit F10, until the thread you were looking at reaches its next instruction, at which point they all pause again. You can see where they are paused in the Threads window. If you freeze one, it won't run at all. The confusing thing is another thread can hit a breakpoint, and then that's the thread you're "looking at", which is different to the other thread that hit a breakpoint

Is there any documentation, which confirms this? - stackoverflow doesn't typically answer questions of "where is the documentation for..", but in terms of your other question, it may help to think of the debugger as like the kids game of musical statues. While the music plays, all threads/children are allowed to run wild, they all stop when the debugger pauses execution/music, and you can single step one thread through a particular set of dance moves by pausing/unpausing the music frequently; while he is moving all the other children will be too (unless you've frozen one or more of them)

If question is what is freeze/thaw, then according to docs, it's suspend/resume. I don't understand your explanation of those to confirm if it's correct or not.

Effectively, you can use three orthogonal mechanisms: 1) wait states threads enter due to your code, for example, when a thread calls a blocking call like System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne, 2) frozen state, 3) wait state at a breakpoint, the mechanisms #2 and #3 applicable to the execution under the debugger.
Note that the method System.Threading.Thread.Suspend is similar (or even identical in effect) to Freeze, but is presently marked obsolete with the System.ObsoleteAttribute, so you cannot do this call. There were some essential reason for this decision; we can discuss them if you have further questions. However, you can still put a thread in a wait state forever using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep using infinite timeout value. It can be useful in some rare situations, but, naturally, not always safe.
That said, any of the wait or frozen states prevent a thread from continuing its execution. It is important to understand that a waiting thread does not consume any CPU time until something wakes it up. It is totally different from any kinds of spin waits. A thread yields to other threads and the operating system's scheduler don't schedule it back to execution until somethings tells the system to wake it up. It happens by 1) unblocking the call, for example, by signalling a WaitHandle mutex, lock, semaphore, blocking read calls, etc., 2) by the command Thaw, 3) by commanding continue at a breakpoint. But then the thread is waken up for continuing execution if two other conditions for its continuation are met.
Here, I don't discuss the aspects of the code controlling the execution of a thread in detail, all kinds of blocking calls, IPC, synchronization, and so on. This is a big separate topic. I just classified this aspect into one big category #1.
On top of it, you control the execution under the debugger. With Visual Studio, for example, you use breakpoints, Main menu > Debug > Start Debugging or Continue (F5), Main menu > Debug > Windows > Threads > context menu > Freeze or Thaw commands.
